# Excel Formula to calculate differences between 2 columns. If A is found in C then D - B. But the list are not in the same order

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have 4 columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

In `A` I have some part numbers, and in `B` I have the quantity. In `C` I have almost the same part numbers but in `D` I have a different quantity.

I need to make the difference between `D` & `B` (`D-B`) if the part number from `C` is found in `A`. The good results should be in `E`

**Image:**

[image]

I tried this formula but it's not to good one.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,FALSE)=A2,D4-B2),"NOT FOUND")
```

This formula is not good because I have to manually put `D4-B2`, `D2-B6`, `D6-B5`, and so on. I have 300 rows to make these differences and I thought maybe there is a formula to calculate this.

Comment: You received three answers here OP - any of them any good? Please consider accepting one or upvoting helpful ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just place the below formula in E2 and select E2 to up to the rows you want and press CTRL + D

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)-B2,"NOT FOUND")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep the code in the `VLOOKUP`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$7,2)-B2;"Not Found")
```

Drag down to autofill. This way, you search the code, but take the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it. Enter formula in E2 and copy/drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$7,C2)<>0,D2-INDEX(B$2:B$7,MATCH(C2,A$2:A$7,0)),"Not Found")
```

or this one:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$D$7,4,0)-B2,"Not Found")
```